# Current Location Map Pin When Button is Pressed

Tags: swift, xcode

I've been trying to make an app where when the mark findings button is pressed, a map pin pops up at the current location of the user.

The problem is that whenever I call the DidUpdateLocations in the IBAction, the map annotation never shows up. However, this function works perfectly if it is outside of the IBAction. And when I call the function both outside and inside the IBAction, there is a continuous stream of map pins displayed.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation


class SecondViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate,MKMapViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!
let manager = CLLocationManager()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()

}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func markStuff(_ sender: Any) {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = locations[0]
        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.001, 0.001)
        let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotationz)
    }

}


}
```

Here is my main.storyboard:

[Main.Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnT12.png)

Comment: can you add screenshot what exactly you want , why you putting didupdatelocation under this action method , its a delegate which gets called evrytime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, move the delegate function `locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])` outside of  `@IBAction func markStuff(_ sender: Any)`

After the line `self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotationz)`, add this line: `manager.stopUpdatingLocation()`, or else it will continue to update your location, thus calling the delegate method, and adding another pin.

Instead of calling `manager.startUpdatingLocation()` in `viewDidLoad`, call it when the button is pressed. The updated code should look like this:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation


class SecondViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate,MKMapViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!
    let manager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func markStuff(_ sender: Any) {

        manager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = locations[0]
        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.001, 0.001)
        let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotationz)
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

}
```

`locationManager(manager:didUpdate...)` isn't being called because it's inside your button's action method... it is being called because the locationManager has updated the location. It will continue to update your location until you tell it otherwise, by calling `manager.stopUpdatingLocation()`.

Comment: Thanks so much. This really helped